# Getting message NIntegrate::nlim when trying to integrate within a For-loop

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages

I want to evaluate an integral that has integration limits `x` and 1.

```
x = Table[i/100, {i, 1, 100}];

mo = Table[i/100, {i, 1, 100}];

For[i = 1, i <= 100, i++,
  mo[[i]] = 
    NIntegrate[
      0.5449597442549279`(1  z)^1.5540952398630834` * z^0.16243884686615462`, 
      {z, x, 1}]]
```

I am getting the error message:

> {0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.1, 0.11, 0.12, 
>   0.13, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16, 0.17, 0.18, 0.19, 0.2, 0.21, 0.22, 0.23, 0.24, 0.25, 0.26, 0.27, 0.28, 0.29, 0.3, 0.31, 0.32, 0.33, 0.34, 0.35, 0.36, 0.37, 0.38, 0.39, 0.4, 0.41, 0.42, 0.43, 0.44, 0.45, 0.46, 0.47, 0.48, 0.49, 0.5, <<50>>} is not a valid limit of integration"

Please help me.

Comment: You want the integral for each number in the list `x`? Maybe ``NDSolveValue[{-y'[z]==0.5449597442549279(1-z)^1.5540952398630834*z^0.16243884686615462`, y[1] == 0}, y, {z, 0, 1}]``

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `For`. Try

```
x = Table[i/100, {i, 1, 100}];
Table[NIntegrate[0.5449597442549279 (1 - z)^1.5540952398630834*z^0.16243884686615462`, {z, x[[i]], 1}], {i, 1, 100}]
(*{0.162334, 0.159651, 0.156776, 0.153787, 0.150722, 0.147607, …}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some other simple ways to do it by turning the `NIntegrate` expression into a pure function of it lower limit of integration and mapping it over a list of the lower list values.

```
NIntegrate[
  0.5449597442549279` z^1.5540952398630834`*z^0.16243884686615462`, {z, #, 1}] & 
/@ 
  Table[i/100, {i, 100}]
```

and

```
NIntegrate[
  0.5449597442549279` z^1.5540952398630834`*z^0.16243884686615462`, {z, #, 1}] & 
/@ 
  Subdivide[1, 100]
```

both give

> ```
> {0.200608, 0.200608, 0.200604, 0.200594, 0.200576, 
>  ..., 
>  0.0210572, 0.0159309, 0.010713, 0.00540294, 0.}
> ```

Although I really recommend avoiding For-loops in Mathematica, such a loop can be used to do what you are trying to do. Like so;

```
Module[{i, n = 100, mo},
  mo = ConstantArray[0, n];
  For[i = 1, i <= n, i++, 
    mo[[i]] = 
    NIntegrate[
      0.5449597442549279` (1 z)^1.5540952398630834`*z^0.16243884686615462`, 
      {z, i/n, 1}]];
  mo]
```

This a safe way to use `For`, but it requires writing a lot more than the other answers you see here and it much slower that those other answers.